# ActivationConfigProperty with configurable clientId

Tags: jms, ejb, websphere-liberty, jms-topic

Using liberty 18.0.0.1 and a MDB like this :

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "distributedACLCache"), 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "distributedACLCache"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "cli-id-01")
```

In this scenario the clientId is staic, but if I want to deploy this MDB in several instances with different clientId's it seems to not be possible ?

Is there a way to inject a clientId from a environment variable or properties from the current runtime ?

/bwa

Answer (score 1):

You can configure all those values using xml (ejb-jar.xml), this way you can change configuration per deployment. I think you can also mix annotation and xml configuration of MDBs.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24977/annotations.htm#WLMDB10006